# Mapping between Entity and ViewModel

Tags: architecture, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to make an application in ASP.NET MVC.
I'm using AutoMapper for the conversion between entities and ViewModels.

In most cases, this works fine, but when I need to add some additional data (f.e. a list of items for a drop-down list), I'm a bit confused about where I should retrieve this data and populate the ViewModel with it (should I do this in the Service-layer/Controller-layer)?

Here is my code:

**Entities**

```
    class Book
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ISBN13 { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    }

    class Genre
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**ViewModels**

```
    class EditBookViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ISBN13 { get; set; }

        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Genre> AllGenres { get; set; }
    }
```

**Service-layer**

```
    class BookService
    {
        public EditBookViewModel GetBookForEdit(int id)
        {
            Book book = _context.Books.Find(id);
            EditBookViewModel vm = _mapper.Map<EditBookViewModel>(book);
            vm.AllGenres = _context.Genres.ToList(); //in Service-layer, or Controller?

            return vm;
        }
    }
```

Is this the right place to create and fill-in the ViewModel? Or should I do this in the Controller-layer?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If your app is going to have a Service Layer and Controllers, then it does not make sense for the service layer to be responsible for composing ViewModels, which are intended to be the interface between a View and a Controller.

The service layer should be something that is view-agnostic.  If another use for the "GetBook" method is needed, it will be polluted with view-specific details.

Your Service Layer should manipulate and return Entities.  Your controller should map those into a ViewModel.